# Custom fonts in codename webbrowser

Tags: codenameone

Please how do i add a custom font to my WebBrowser in Codename one. This is what I tried using but didn't work.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'feast';
    src: url('/feasfbrg.ttf');
}

body {font-family: 'feast';}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either point the URL at a web address to download the font or package the HTML hierarchy as explained in this blog post and use a relative not absolute path:

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/html-hierarchy-release-plan-teavm.html

Comment: Hi Shai, Thank you for the response, but I'm yet to solve the problem after so many tries in different ways. 
I placed the html file and font inside the html package. Every thing is fine except the custom font. Can you point out what is wrong with the code? 
`<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face { font-family: JuneBug; src: url(/webfont.ttf); }
h1 {
font-family: JuneBug
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hey, June</h1>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: relative path. Remove the / before webfont.ttf

Comment: Tried that already. It didn't work. Maybe you should try it out yourself. Probably there is a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to narrow it down:

Instead of bundling the font in the package, just host it at a URL, then try referencing that URL directly.  And get that working. 
e.g.

```
src: url(http://example.com/path/to/fesfbrg.ttf)
```

Once you have that working, then you can start focus on getting the URL correct for a locally bundled font.

Can you share the code snippet where you load the page into the WebBrowser?  That might give some clues.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Steve, I've given up on that for now since its not its not absolutely necessary for my app. I've tried that as well, still did not work (even though I intended using locally bundled fonts). The code, is a simple hand coded form with the web browser as the only component and the html code i provided under Shai's comment (I am trying out things in CN1 to redesign one of my android app). I followed the instruction provided in the link provided by Shai. Btw you can still give me a working code that u have used.

Comment: I don't have any exact snippets using custom .ttf.  It should be supported on modern mobile browsers though, so if it isn't working for you even from a full http url, then it is a css/html problem, not a CN1 problem.  The procedure for debugging such an issue is:

1. Create a normal web page with what you want and view it in Chrome.  Make sure it works.
2. Try to load webpage directly from the web inside your CN1 Web view.  Make sure it works.
3. Try to embed page locally in your app - but set font url to use http: address.  Make sure it works.
4. Embed the font locally....